# Fail to extract sonar-scanner-api-batch.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I am unable to run a sonar scan in my local windows machine. I am facing the below error. Please me a suggestion.

Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to extract sonar-scanner-api-batch.jar: **C:Users\AppData\Local\1\Temp\1\Sonar-scammer-api\batch6587863709717232481.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process**

Comment: Kindly refer to this [ask].

Comment: Restart your computer first and see if this solves your problem.